# How can I determine the top/left position of a label in WPF?

Tags: wpf, label, flowlayoutpanel

I have a WPF label contained in a FlowLayoutPanel and I want to determine the position of the label when clicked with the mouse.  I am trying to position a pop-up control where near to the label and just need it's location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Popup` control has this ability built-in. You can use the `Placement`, `PlacementTarget`, `HorizontalOffset` and `VerticalOffset` properties to control it.

That said, if you really want to find a point relative to another control, use the [`UIElement.TranslatePoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.translatepoint.aspx) method.